# IDM not able to download .dmg file

Tags: windows, download-manager

I am trying to download the `.dmg` extension file with Internet Download Manager (v. 6.07) on windows 7.
At the time I start the download, the extension is `.dmg` but after getting download it changes to `.bz2` .
Usually, I am facing this problem with larger files otherwise smaller files get downloaded correctly.

Comment: Which is your browser ?

Comment: i am using google chrome.

Comment: I had this same issue several times before. I use chrome and IDM. IDM won't pick some type of files to download.

Comment: my idm picks up the files with .dmg extension for that i added dmg extension to the extension list. but the problem is after getting downloaded its extension changes and i am forced to open that file with 7-zip.

Answer (score 0):

After all of this year, somehow this issue still persists to this day. I have installed IDM (latest version 6.38) on my Windows computer and it is not picking the `.dmg` files in the first place

To solve it...

1. Make sure the IDM extension is properly installed in your browser.
2. Select the `.dmg` file using your mouse pointer, "**Download with IDM**" option will appear, just click on that.

[image: img_downloadIDM]

(In case,  "**Download with IDM**" option is not appearing, follow the Step 3)

3. Open IDM -> Click on the "**Add URL**" button -> Copy and paste the website address to IDM URL bar -> Put a forward slash ( **/** ) after that -> Again copy the file name and put it after that slash -> Hit the "OK" button

[image: idm_gif]